# Why is my jQuery .css() code not applying styles?

Tags: jquery, css

I looked about multiple existing posts and none had a solution for me.

**Edit:** Someone asked why I'm using `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`. **This is a Wordpress site.** You have to wrap your jQuery like this if you want to use `$` since `$` is used by the Wordpress framework and will break your code.

### Update

Here is the code that creates the button dynamically. I wouldn't have done it this way, but I've inherited the site when I started working here:

```
$('nav').before('<button class="menu-btn" role="button" aria-pressed="false"><span>toggle menu</span></button>'); 
        $('nav .sub-menu').before('<button class="sub-menu-toggle" role="button" aria-pressed="false"></button>');
```

Not only are the styles not being applied, they are *not even visible* in dev tools so I know they're not simply being overridden by inline styles or something. The jQuery css isn't being loaded at all.

#### Details:

- There are no errors in the console log.
- No errors when ran through JS Hint
- Chrome debugger shows the code executed
- Chrome Elements tab does **not** show the styles as loaded
- `.site-title`'s styles are applied perfectly
- `.menu-btn` is not applying at all.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.site-title').css({
    'grid-column-start': '2',
    'grid-column-end': '6'
  });

  $('.menu-btn').css({
    'top': 'unset',
    'right': 'unset',
    'left': '10px',
    'bottom': '15px',
    'z-index': '100',
    'position': 'fixed'
  });
});
```

When the *same styles* are added via CSS they apply correctly.

```
body > div.site-container > button.menu-btn {
  top: unset;
  right: unset;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Maybe give a try with `jQuery(function($) { /.../ });`.

Comment: @Johannes This is for a Wordpress site. `$` is used by the Wordpress framework so you have wrap your jQuery in that if you want to use `$`.

Comment: Works for me - https://jsfiddle.net/8dkqhum2/ - Are you 100% sure your script is reaching that point?

Comment: @MDrX Safari debugger shows that it's being executed.

Comment: A useful link: https://www.sitepoint.com/types-document-ready/

Comment: @MDrX https://imgur.com/a/WUXpd1S you can see here in the Safari debugger what is executed and what is not. Faded out code (in red box) not executed. Green box text was executed. `.c-hamburger` = `.menu-btn` (I didn't name it...)

Comment: @D4V1D I tried it, same result unfortunately.

Comment: You say this is WP, so is jQuery loaded before your script? Have you tried doing this instead `(function($){ $(document).ready(function(){ PUT YOUR CODE HERE}); })(jQuery);`?

Comment: @Johannes it's actually good practice to do that, and should not be removed. That argument is `jQuery` and allows you to reference a local copy. This is useful where there's are conflicting libraries fighting for `$`, or you released jQuery's control of that variable using `$.noConflict()`. Here's a more obvious example: https://jsfiddle.net/qocmy91x/

Comment: Is the button being created dynamically? If so, you'll need to make use of `.on()` - http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: @ disinfor I'll give this a shot ,but all of the other code executes correctly. Please see above. Both code blocks are in the same wrapper. One works, the other does not. I do not believe the wrapper is the problem, otherwise both would break, correct?

Comment: What happens if you try executing one of those snippets in the DevTools console? Have you confirmed (in the console) that jQuery is loaded / works?

Comment: @MDrX Yes! Could that be part of the problem? I'll update my post with that info too. Didn't know it would be relevant.

Comment: @Marie it does. See the section titled 'Aliasing the jQuery Object` in your link. If it didn't do that then my example in the fiddle wouldn't work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry, I missed that, good to know and thank you!

Comment: @MDrX THAT DID IT. Thanks for your help! Why don't you add that as an answer and I'll give you the green check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MDrX figured it out. My `.menu-btn` was being created dynamically so added my code to the same block that created the button and it worked!

#### Final result:

```
    // Add Mobile Menu Button
    $('nav').before('<button class=".menu-btn" role="button" aria-pressed="false"><span>toggle menu</span></button>'); // Add toggles to menus
    $('nav .sub-menu').before('<button class="sub-menu-toggle" role="button" aria-pressed="false"></button>');
    $('.menu-btn').css ({
        'top':'unset',
        'right':'unset',
        'left':'10px',
        'bottom':'15px',
        'z-index':'100',
        'position':'fixed'
    });
```

I'm posting the answer here for now, but I'm waiting to see if @MDrX will post an answer so that I can give him the credit and that sweet, sweet rep :)